# Saving vector layer with joins converts joined attributes from double to integer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I'm using QGIS 2.16.3. I'm trying to use the "Dissolve with Stats" plugin, which requires me to save the layer with the joined attributes. However, saving the layer converts the joined fields from double to integer, and I need to preserve that precision.

Comment: I am not sure if there is something you can do to preserve the attribute type. But i "offer you" a workaround that may be useful: you can save the layer and reconvert the joined fields with Processing plugin:
'Commander > Processing algorithm: Refactor fields'.
You can change the attribute type, length and precision (so you can have again your desired precision). I hope it works.

Comment: Another possible workaround is to save the joined shapefile **as a new shapefile** using the `Save As..` option. This should retain the field type and then use this with the plugin?